# CakePHP find list of associated items where id is

Tags: php, list, cakephp, find, associations

I want to create in cake php application with users, games and games platforms (for ex PS3)
I got tables:

userGames (game have one platform)
id, name, platform_id

users (users can have many platforms)
id, username

platforms
id, name

users_platforms
id, platform_id, user_id

And now i want to select all user id=1 platforms, and list it for select tag.
Here is sql query:

```
SELECT platforms.name, platforms.id FROM platforms LEFT JOIN platforms_users ON platforms_users.platform_id=platforms.id WHERE platforms_users.user_id=1
```

But i dont know what to list this by find('list') function in cakePHP
I try type in users controller:

$this->User->Platform->find('list', array('conditions', array('User.id'=>'1')));

But this returns sql problem (undefinded User.id)
Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please try this

```
$this->loadModel('UserPlatform');
$this->UserPlatform->bindModel(array(
    'belongsTo' => array('Platform')
));
$this->UserPlatform->find('list', array(
    'fields' => array('Platform.id','Platform.name'),
    'conditions' => array('UserPlatform.user_id'=>'1'),
    'recursive' => 1
));
```

Answer (score 0):

you must apply find function on join table

Your find must same as this:

```
 $this->PlatformUser->find('list',array('fields'=>
 array('Platform.name','Platform.id'),'conditions'=> array('PlatformUser.id' => 1)));
```

Your PlatformUser Model must have:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Platform' => array(
        'className' => 'Platform',
        'foreignKey' => 'platform_id',
    ),
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is actually a HasAndBelongsToMany Association.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html

> hasAndBelongsToMany (HABTM)
>
> We’ll need to set up an extra table in the database to handle HABTM associations. This new join table’s name needs to include the names of both models involved, in alphabetical order, and separated with an underscore ( _ ). The contents of the table should be two fields that are foreign keys (which should be integers) pointing to the primary keys of the involved models. To avoid any issues, don’t define a combined primary key for these two fields. If your application requires a unique index, you can define one. If you plan to add any extra information to this table, or use a ‘with’ model, you should add an additional primary key field (by convention ‘id’).
>
> HABTM requires a separate join table that includes both model names.

(This would be the UserPlatform-table if I got that right.)

> Make sure primary keys in tables cakes and recipes have “id” fields as assumed by convention. If they’re different than assumed, they must be changed in model’s primaryKey.

```
class Recipe extends AppModel {
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'Ingredient' =>
        array(
            'className' => 'Ingredient',
            'joinTable' => 'ingredients_recipes',
            'foreignKey' => 'recipe_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'ingredient_id',
            'unique' => true,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'with' => ''
        )
);
}
```

Comment: You might want to add some of the key data provided in the linked document in case the linked to page ever gets deleted.